# How can I add a click event to take you to a certain image on a slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slide with images for a digital book set into 3 chapters. The slider is working, but how do I add the click event on the "Chapter" divs, that are in the html, so that when I click on them, it scrolls to the correct spot in the slider. i.e. if you click on Chapter 2, it takes you to the slide that starts chapter 2. This is using jquery.

HTML

```
<div class="chapters">
    <div class="chapterOne">
            <h3>Stony Brook Medicine</h3>

            <h4>Chapter 1</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="chapterTwo">
            <h3>Stony Brook Childrens</h3>

            <h4>Chapter 2</h4>  
    </div>
    <div class="chapterThree">
            <h3>Working together while standing out</h3>

            <h4>Chapter 3</h4>  
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sliderContainer">
    <ul>
        <li class="chapterOneSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/F44D5E"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterOneSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/CEBAC9"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterOneSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/56DC28"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterOneSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/CEBAC9"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterOneSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/56DC28"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterOneSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/CEBAC9"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterOneSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/56DC28"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterOneSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/CEBAC9"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterOneSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/56DC28"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterTwoSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/CEBAC9"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterTwoSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/56DC28"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterTwoSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/CEBAC9"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterTwoSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/56DC28"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterTwoSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/CEBAC9"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterThreeSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/56DC28"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterThreeSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/CEBAC9"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterThreeSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/56DC28"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterThreeSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/CEBAC9"><a class="arrow next">&rang;</a><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chapterThreeSlide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/875x369/E5A470"><a class="arrow prev">&lang;</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the jquery

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var theImage = $('ul li img');
    var theWidth = theImage.width()
    //wrap into mother div
    $('ul').wrap('<div id="mother" />');
    //assign height width and overflow hidden to mother
    $('#mother').css({
        width: function () {
            return theWidth;
        },
        height: function () {
            return theImage.height();
        },
        position: 'relative',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    });
    //get total of image sizes and set as width for ul
    var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
    $('ul').css({
        width: function () {
            return totalWidth;
        }
    });


    $(theImage).each(

    function (intIndex) {
        $(this).nextAll('a')
            .bind("click", function () {
            if ($(this).is(".next")) {
                $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                    "margin-left": (-(intIndex + 1) * theWidth)
                }, 1000)
            } else if ($(this).is(".prev")) {
                $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                    "margin-left": (-(intIndex - 1) * theWidth)
                }, 1000)
            } else if ($(this).is(".startover")) {
                $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
                    "margin-left": (0)
                }, 1000)
            }
        }); //close .bind()
    }); //close .each()
});
```

CSS

```
    .sliderContainer {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 875px;
    height: 369px;
    position: relative
}
.sliderContainer:hover .arrow {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;   
}
.arrow {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(183,3,3,0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 162px;
    position: absolute;
}
.next {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.prev {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
ul {
    padding: 0; 
    margin:0;
}
ul li {
  float:left; 
  list-style:none; 
  position:relative; 
}
```

Comment: Your CSS would help as well.

Comment: and a jsfiddle will do more then the world

Comment: `$('.chapterTwo').click(function(){ $('.sliderContainer ul').animate({"margin-left": (-10 * theWidth)}, 1000)}); });` as your chapter two li is 10 places in. Sorry I don't have time atm to do a full answer, but this should help you start off.

Comment: Added CSS.  Thank you @gaynorvader. That definitely gets me going and shows me what I was doing wrong in my attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS only as well **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/qr85zbcx/)**, just changed the `.chapters` inner divs into `a` tags and set the target `a href="#foo"` in the first slide of each slide `li id="foo"` it will jump to that chapter with slight fadein effect

**CSS:**

```
 :target {
   animation: slideFadeIn 2s ease;
 }
 @keyframes slideFadeIn {
   0% {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
     opacity: 1;
   }
 }
```